# im lost with validating my code

Tags: php, html, validation

can someone help me validate my codes? user should only able to input numeric or integer only. 
i have already tried using ctype_digit isnumeric and some more else , but probably because i didnt quite understand on how to use it nothing was successful

```
<?php
    $table = '';

    if ($_POST) {
        $table .= '<table border="4">';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['rows']; $i++) {
            $table .= '<tr>';
            for ($j = 0; $j < $_POST['column']; $j++) {
                $table .= '<td width="100">&nbsp;</td>';
            }
            $table .= '</tr>';
        }
        $table .= '</table>';
    }

?>

<?php echo "A table with "; echo $_POST['rows']; echo " row(s) and "; echo  $_POST['column']; echo " column(s) " ;?>

<?php
    echo $table;

?>


             <form action="" method="post">
        <table border="0" width="729">
            <tr>
                <td width="39"><label>Rows :</label></td>
                <td width="144"><input type="text" name="rows"></td>

                <td width="51" ><label>Column :</label></td>
                <td width="352" ><input type="text" name="column"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Create table"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    

    </form>
    <br />
    <br />
```

by the way the form should validate using PHP . thank you in advance !!

Comment: The code you've added does not appear to be attempting any validation. I don't see either `ctype_digit` or `isnumeric`. And what do you mean by "nothing was successful"? Were there errors? If so, what were they? For debugging questions you really need to show exactly what you did and describe _how_ it didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to : limit user input to numerical values, or : check user input and warn him if the value werent numerical ?

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes there is no validation because i dont even put. nothing was successful was referring to when i put some validation code i learn from googling . and because i didnt success i delete the code back . there is no error in my code here , the only thing i want is to validate my code into numeric input only .

Answer (score 0):

thank guys , sorry for any inconvenience i complete my code .

```
<?php
    $table = '';
    $row= $_POST['rows'];
    $column=$_POST['column'];
    if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){
        if($row=="")
        $error= "error : please fill out row";

        else if($column=="")
        $error= "error : please fill out column";

        elseif(is_numeric($row)==FALSE)
        $error= "error number only";

        elseif(is_numeric($column)==FALSE)
        $error= "error number only";

        else
        {

        $table .= '<table border="4">';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['rows']; $i++) {
            $table .= '<tr>';
            for ($j = 0; $j < $_POST['column']; $j++) {
                $table .= '<td width="100">&nbsp;</td>';
            }
            $table .= '</tr>';
        }
        $table .= '</table>';


echo "A table with "; echo $row; echo " row(s) and "; echo  $column; echo " column(s) " ;

    echo $table;

    }
    }
?>
    <?php 
    if (isset($error))
    {
        echo "<font color='FF0000'><center><b>". $error .
        "</b></center></font>";
    }
    ?>

             <form action="" method="post" >
        <table border="0" width="729">
            <tr>
                <td width="39"><label>Rows :</label></td>
                <td width="144"><input type="text" name="rows"></td>

                <td width="51" ><label>Column :</label></td>
                <td width="352" ><input type="text" name="column"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create table"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    

    </form>
    <br />
    <br />
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question wasn't very clear but I don't know if something like this would work for you.

```
<?php
$table = '';

if ($_POST) {
  if(is_numeric($_POST['postVariable'] && is_int($_POST['postVariable']) {
    $table .= '<table border="4">';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['rows']; $i++) {
        $table .= '<tr>';
        for ($j = 0; $j < $_POST['column']; $j++) {
            $table .= '<td width="100">&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        $table .= '</tr>';
    }
    $table .= '</table>';
   } else {
      return 'you error message'; 
   }

}


?>
```

Comment: Maybe you should wait to see if the question can be clarified before attempting to answer?